# What is the mechanical advantage of this chain drive arrangement?

Tags: gears

Trying to figure out if this has a mechanical advantage on moving a 600 pound car faster with less effort than just two using 2 gears[image]

Comment: bottom configuration has higher friction losses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only advantage of the lower arrangement is that it allows the motor sprocket to be offset from the 12:72 tooth final drive chain.

The 14:14 ratio changes nothing other than introduce additional friction losses on the chain and shaft bearings as well as some additional weight and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is "the" advantage you might be looking for, but an advantage could be that due to the smaller difference in gear size, more teeth are engaged to the chain in the smaller gear-wheels. This may reduce the strength required of the gear teeth.

That is however a small advantage compared to the increased complexity of the bottom setup. The lower setup will most likely also not result in less effort (if by "effort" you mean mechanical work/power), and only result in more wait.

Comment: The strength of the chain and gears it’s not a problem using harden steel gears on a 530 Race chain …just thought the 4 gears would help on the weight of the car .thinking that 4 gears would be think it’s only pulling 400 lbs instead of 600 lbs with less effort